# How can I mock the indexing operator with dart mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, operators, mockito

I am writing a unit test in which I need to mock a JsObject so that I don't need to do actual javascript interop in my test.  However, I'm using the indexing operator `[]` to access a field in my JsObject. I am using the dart mockito library https://github.com/fibulwinter/dart-mockito for mocking and I can't seem to find how I go about mocking the behavior of operators on the mocked object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito makes stubbing very easy, stubbing the index operator works like stubbing any other method. Imaging that you want to stub the index operator of the following class:

```
class IndexTest {
  operator[] (String value);
}
```

In the first step we create a mock for that class:

```
class MockIndexTest extends Mock implements IndexTest {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
}
```

Now in you test you can set the return values that you expect for invocations using the index operator:

```
  test('Test', () {
    final t = new MockIndexTest();

    // Set return values
    when(t[any]).thenReturn(0); // 1
    when(t['one']).thenReturn(1); // 2
    when(t['two']).thenReturn(2); // 3

    // Check return values
    expect(t['one'], equals(1));
    expect(t['two'], equals(2));
    expect(t['something else'], equals(0));
  });
```

Without stubbing a call always returns `null`. With the `any` value provided by mockito you can set the default return value for calls with any argument (see 1). You can also set the return value for a specific set of parameters (see 2 and 3). You have to set the default value before setting the specific ones.